# SQLite DATETIME column with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, sqlite, datetime, ef-database-first

I have an existing SQLite database that I want to use in Entity Framework. However SQLite's weird type system means you can even

```
create table temp(temp datetime);
insert into temp values ('whatever');
```

The dates are stored as [Unix time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) integers. My model classes are autogenerated by Visual Studio, so how do I tell the code generator to handle these dates correctly and not make the application throw

> String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

exceptions on startup?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to change your connection string to something like

```
data source=&quot;|DataDirectory|\data.sqlite&quot;;datetimeformat=UnixEpoch;datetimekind=Utc
```

You can change these settings in `Server Explorer/<right click your  connection>/Modify Connection/Advanced`, but changing the settings there will *not propagate* to your App.config connection string.