# SQLite and EntityFramework, formatexception on timestamp

Tags: entity-framework, sqlite, timestamp

I'm trying to access a SQLite Database with EntityFramework. When I try to query a field of type "timestamp" with LINQ I get a FormatException. I couldn't find a answer to this anyone else seems to work with regular sql queries. It may be Important that the DB is coming from an iOS app.

This is my code:

```
using (var db = new WorkTimesEntities())
{
    var times = db.ZDAYs.ToList();
    foreach (var item in times)
    {
       Console.WriteLine(item.ZDATEOFDAY+"\t"+item.ZDURATION+"\t"+item.ZMONTH);
    }
}
```

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, these threads helped me out:

[SQLite DATETIME column with Entity Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24315887/sqlite-datetime-column-with-entity-framework)

Explained me that I have to modify the connection string in App.config by myself.

[keyword not supported data source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1404268/keyword-not-supported-data-source)
And this one showed me the correct syntax for the connection string.

Answer (score 0):

In SQLlite a timestamp is in Unix time, that is the number of seconds since 1.1.1970.

Since you are getting a format exception on a query, it must be related to how you are setting the query parameter for the datetime field. For example are you sending in a string that is a formatted datetime?

If you need more help post your Linq query.